# How to configure Spring Authorization Server to be Backwards Compatible with old Spring Security OAuth2?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have been using the previous version of Spring Security OAuth 2 for several years. Now, with the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.1.0, I am moving to the new packages. In particular, I am implementing Spring Authorization Server.

The old OAuth2 package had a `DefaultTokenServices` that took a simple signing key to sign the JWT tokens. However, Spring Auth Server appears much more complex.

I have tens of thousands of users out there now with "old" JWT tokens. When I roll out this upgrade I do not want them all to have to re-authorize.

How can I configure Spring Authorization Server to make it compatible with the old token format?  (I realize this is more of a Resource Server question, but Auth Server will have to product JWT tokens that are compatible with Resource Server which should be compatible with legacy...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be involved. The new Nimbus packages, when using a symmetric key (which my legacy system does) will not work with key lengths of less than 256 characters - but the old key is much shorter than that.  So in order to keep legacy compatibility, I had to re-use the old mechanisms to authenticate the tokens already out there in the wild.

First, I had to re-add the old Spring Security OAuth (I thought about just extracting the necessary classes, thinking it can't be that hard, but you need about 100).

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I need an `AuthenticationProvider` that can handle the legacy-style tokens. The new-style class is `JwtAuthenticationProvider`, while the old-style class was `OAuth2AuthenticationManager`. So somehow I had to bridge that gap.

I created this, which is a mixture of the appropriate code of both:

```
public class LegacyOauthAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;
    
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    
    private Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        BearerTokenAuthenticationToken bearer = (BearerTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        String token = bearer.getToken();
        
        OAuth2Authentication oauth2Auth;
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;
        try
        {
            oauth2Auth = tokenServices.loadAuthentication(token);
            accessToken = tokenServices.readAccessToken(token);
            if(oauth2Auth == null)
            {
                logger.warn("Invalid token");
                return null;
            }
            if(accessToken == null)
            {
                logger.warn("We lack the information to create a JWT object");
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidTokenException e)
        {
            // This means it's a new-style token, don't blow up.
            logger.debug("New style OAuth token detected", e);
            return null;
        }
        
        checkClientDetails(oauth2Auth);

        String tokenValue = token;
        Instant issuedAt = null;
        Instant expiresAt = Instant.now().plusSeconds(10000);
        // the headers are lost, but this is what they were
        Map<String, Object> headers = Map.of("alg", "HS256", "typ", "JWT");  
        Map<String, Object> claims = accessToken.getAdditionalInformation();
        // Missing scope
        claims.put("scope", accessToken.getScope());
        Jwt jwt = new Jwt(tokenValue, issuedAt, expiresAt, headers, claims);

        AbstractAuthenticationToken aat = this.jwtAuthenticationConverter.convert(jwt);
        if (aat.getDetails() == null) 
        {
            aat.setDetails(bearer.getDetails());
        }
        this.logger.debug("Authenticated JWT token");
        return aat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
    {
        return BearerTokenAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    private void checkClientDetails(OAuth2Authentication auth)
    {
        if(clientDetailsService != null)
        {
            ClientDetails client;
            try
            {
                client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId());
            }
            catch(ClientRegistrationException e)
            {
                throw new OAuth2AccessDeniedException("Invalid token contains invalid client id");
            }
            Set<String> allowed = client.getScope();
            for(String scope : auth.getOAuth2Request().getScope())
            {
                if(!allowed.contains(scope))
                {
                    throw new OAuth2AccessDeniedException(
                            "Invalid token contains disallowed scope for this client");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTokenServices(DefaultTokenServices tokenServices)
    {
        this.tokenServices = tokenServices;
    }

    public void setJwtAuthenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> jwtAuthenticationConverter)
    {
        this.jwtAuthenticationConverter = jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService)
    {
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }
}
```

This is added to the main `AuthenticationManager` as a provider.

Config for this guy is like this

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices legacyTokenServices()
    {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(legacyTokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(legacyJwtTokenEnhancer());
        defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(legacyClientDetailsService());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore legacyTokenStore()
    {
        return new JwtTokenStore(legacyJwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter legacyJwtTokenEnhancer()
    {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(keySource.legacySigningKeyString());
        return converter;
    }
    
    @Bean 
    public ClientDetailsService legacyClientDetailsService()
    {
        JdbcClientDetailsService svc = new JdbcClientDetailsService(datasource);
        svc.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return svc;
    }
    
    // We need this because the principal claim is different too
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter legacyJwtAuthenticationConverter() 
    {
        RoleMemberJwtGrantedAuthenticationConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new RoleMemberJwtGrantedAuthenticationConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setPrincipalClaimName("user_name");
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    
    @Bean
    public LegacyOauthAuthenticationProvider legacyJwtAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        LegacyOauthAuthenticationProvider legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider = new LegacyOauthAuthenticationProvider();
        legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(legacyJwtAuthenticationConverter());
        legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider.setTokenServices(legacyTokenServices());
        legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider.setClientDetailsService(legacyClientDetailsService());
        return legacyOauthAuthenticationProvider;
    }
```

With all of this, both the legacy- and the new-style tokens are recoginized. Be sure to put the legacy provider *in front* of the new provider - the new provider will blow up if it finds a JWT token that it doesn't like. That's why this legacy adapter swallows the `InvalidTokenException`.  If it's truly invalid, like some kind of attack, the next provider will puke it up.

Answer (score 0):

To control the key pair used to sign and validate your JWTs, simply publish a `JWKSource` `@Bean` as mentioned in the [JWK Set Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#jwk-set-endpoint) section of the reference.

`JWKSource` is an interface from the [nimbus-jose-jwt](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) library, so check their docs for more information on this interface. You can find an example in the [Defining Required Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components) section on the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html) page, which defines an in-memory key that you can easily replace with your own key(s) or a key rotation strategy. Here is [another example](https://github.com/sjohnr/sas-native-demo/blob/929e543c0646dcf4663ec070d2e91bb0d56e462a/src/main/java/com/example/SecurityConfig.java#L56-L78) that loads the keys from a static file.

Comment: That was my first hope...but because my signing key was too short, I cannot use the new code - it blows up saying the key must be at least 256 characters. And it wasn't.

Comment: Then I would strongly encourage you to perform a key rotation to a stronger key on your legacy system first. Users that log in frequently can benefit from the new key. Users who don't log in during the rotation period but do log in later can be informed their token was revoked to enhance security.

Comment: This is for an Alexa skill integration.  People expect to link their accounts once, and have it work for a long long time.  They hate it when the skill disconnects.  So I don't have that option.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you rotate the key used to sign the access token (while keeping the old key for validation), assuming the legacy impl provides a refresh token, which should be an opaque (not signed) value. So users who are using the skill within, say 2 months, and use the refresh token to get a new access token will obtain tokens signed with a fresh key. Anyone who hasn't used the skill in 2 months (or even longer if you want), and use it only after the new version is deployed would need to re-link. Depending on how long your rotation period is, that should be very few users.

Comment: Otherwise, it seems you're talking about moving forward with a new implementation that uses an insecure signing key. And speaking of signing keys, are you using a symmetric key or asymmetric key pair?

Comment: That's essentially what I've done...new tokns will be generated by the new framework, while old tokens will continue to be recognized.  Eventually, right, no one will be left on the old tokens scheme.